# Backtrader library not properly calculating trades

Tags: python, pandas, debugging, algorithmic-trading, back-testing

I am using backtrader in python to use for my strategy. I already tried printing the parts where the errors might have occured but I still haven't figured this out.
The title might be wrong as well because the backtrader might be just working well (and the error might be on my end).

here is my full code:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1d__tKGTipWkVXkiYNVwoKXFCqlysKxvB?usp=sharing

Why is the trade value and the portfolio value not calculated or updated properly?

In the **April-June 2022 short trade**, the value of that trade should have been around 1300 USD right?
cause it's around 30% profit?

Also, the total portfolio value must have changed with accordance to that trade value, right?

why is it not??

**From here, I think the profits/losses are not calculated properly:
**

2022-02-04, Close, 41550.00
2022-02-05, Close, 41374.69
2022-02-05, BUY CREATE 1000.0 USDT BTCUSDT
2022-02-06, BUY EXECUTED, Price: 41374.68, Cost: 999.9997583063462, Comm 0.0
2022-02-06, PORTFOLIO VALUE: 100023.84718773724
2022-02-06, Close, 42361.35
2022-02-07, Close, 43829.99

2022-02-20, Close, 38368.10
2022-02-21, Close, 36986.40
2022-02-21, CLOSING POSITION
2022-02-21, SELL CREATE 990.0000024169365 USDT BTCUSDT
2022-02-22, SELL EXECUTED, Price: 36986.4, Cost: 999.9997583063462, Comm 0.0
2022-02-22, PORTFOLIO VALUE: 99861.13291803387
2022-02-22, SELL EXECUTED, Price: 36986.4, Cost: -990.0000024169365, Comm 0.0
2022-02-22, PORTFOLIO VALUE: 99861.13291803387
2022-02-22, Close, 38212.00
2022-02-23, Close, 37227.80

2022-03-03, Close, 42449.50
2022-03-04, Close, 39127.70
2022-03-04, CLOSING POSITION
2022-03-04, BUY CREATE 1008.8393805971718 USDT BTCUSDT
2022-03-05, BUY EXECUTED, Price: 39127.7, Cost: -990.0000024169365, Comm 0.0
2022-03-05, PORTFOLIO VALUE: 99843.00152341062
2022-03-05, BUY EXECUTED, Price: 39127.7, Cost: 1008.8393805971718, Comm 0.0
2022-03-05, PORTFOLIO VALUE: 99843.00152341062
2022-03-05, Close, 39375.10
2022-03-06, Close, 38401.10

2022-03-11, Close, 38713.00
2022-03-11, CLOSING POSITION
2022-03-11, SELL CREATE 988.2778336607064 USDT BTCUSDT
2022-03-12, SELL EXECUTED, Price: 38713.1, Cost: 1008.8393805971718, Comm 0.0
2022-03-12, PORTFOLIO VALUE: 99823.90350865477
2022-03-12, SELL EXECUTED, Price: 38713.1, Cost: -988.2803864926585, Comm 0.0
2022-03-12, PORTFOLIO VALUE: 99823.90350865477
2022-03-12, Close, 38792.60
2022-03-13, Close, 37743.70

2022-03-21, Close, 40982.00
2022-03-21, CLOSING POSITION
2022-03-21, BUY CREATE 1008.1421339654944 USDT BTCUSDT
2022-03-22, BUY EXECUTED, Price: 40982.0, Cost: -988.2803864926585, Comm 0.0
2022-03-22, PORTFOLIO VALUE: 99801.65918305461
2022-03-22, BUY EXECUTED, Price: 40982.0, Cost: 1008.1421339654944, Comm 0.0
2022-03-22, PORTFOLIO VALUE: 99801.65918305461
2022-03-22, Close, 42349.80
2022-03-23, Close, 42867.90

2022-04-08, Close, 42229.20
2022-04-09, Close, 42727.70
2022-04-09, CLOSING POSITION
2022-04-09, SELL CREATE 987.5986967192749 USDT BTCUSDT
2022-04-10, SELL EXECUTED, Price: 42727.8, Cost: 1008.1421339654944, Comm 0.0
2022-04-10, PORTFOLIO VALUE: 99824.53487900045
2022-04-10, SELL EXECUTED, Price: 42727.8, Cost: -987.6010080973664, Comm 0.0
2022-04-10, PORTFOLIO VALUE: 99824.53487900045
2022-04-10, Close, 42140.40
2022-04-11, Close, 39505.60

2022-05-31, Close, 31797.80
2022-06-01, Close, 29796.90
2022-06-01, CLOSING POSITION
2022-06-01, BUY CREATE 1007.9855885218949 USDT BTCUSDT
2022-06-02, BUY EXECUTED, Price: 29796.9, Cost: -987.6010080973664, Comm 0.0
2022-06-02, PORTFOLIO VALUE: 100131.49686425681
2022-06-02, BUY EXECUTED, Price: 29796.9, Cost: 1007.9855885218949, Comm 0.0
2022-06-02, PORTFOLIO VALUE: 100131.49686425681
2022-06-02, Close, 30437.10
2022-06-03, Close, 29682.80

2022-06-12, Close, 26564.70
2022-06-12, CLOSING POSITION
2022-06-12, SELL CREATE 991.0185424517899 USDT BTCUSDT
2022-06-13, SELL EXECUTED, Price: 26564.7, Cost: 1007.9855885218949, Comm 0.0
2022-06-13, PORTFOLIO VALUE: 100153.19950937488
2022-06-13, SELL EXECUTED, Price: 26564.7, Cost: -991.0185424517899, Comm 0.0
2022-06-13, PORTFOLIO VALUE: 100153.19950937488
2022-06-13, Close, 22471.50
2022-06-14, Close, 22122.70

2022-07-10, Close, 20853.80
2022-07-10, CLOSING POSITION
2022-07-10, BUY CREATE 1009.9151777296173 USDT BTCUSDT
2022-07-11, BUY EXECUTED, Price: 20853.8, Cost: -991.0185424517899, Comm 0.0
2022-07-11, PORTFOLIO VALUE: 100169.98786941443
2022-07-11, BUY EXECUTED, Price: 20853.8, Cost: 1009.9151777296173, Comm 0.0
2022-07-11, PORTFOLIO VALUE: 100169.98786941443
2022-07-11, Close, 19954.30
2022-07-12, Close, 19322.90

**I think the profits/losses are not calculated properly
I tried to cross-check each trade with this data:
**
Date     Price
0   2022-02-04  41550.00
1   2022-02-05  41374.69
2   2022-02-06  42361.35
3   2022-02-07  43829.99
4   2022-02-20  38368.10
5   2022-02-21  36986.40
6   2022-02-22  38212.00
7   2022-02-23  37227.80
8   2022-03-03  42449.50
9   2022-03-04  39127.70
10  2022-03-05  39375.10
11  2022-03-06  38401.10
12  2022-03-11  38713.00
13  2022-03-12  38792.60
14  2022-03-13  37743.70
15  2022-03-21  40982.00
16  2022-03-22  42349.80
17  2022-03-23  42867.90
18  2022-04-08  42229.20
19  2022-04-09  42727.70
20  2022-04-10  42140.40
21  2022-04-11  39505.60
22  2022-05-31  31797.80
23  2022-06-01  29796.90
24  2022-06-02  30437.10
25  2022-06-03  29682.80
26  2022-06-12  26564.70
27  2022-06-13  22471.50
28  2022-06-14  22122.70
29  2022-07-10  20853.80
30  2022-07-11  19954.30
31  2022-07-12  19322.90

I tried to backtest a certain moving average strategy but got some issues with backtrader (or maybe just my code)

Comment: Hi there, and thanks for submitting a question to StackOverflow. Contributors can help you much more quickly if you trim your question to one very specific issue (with code samples and what you expect the output to be, not a link to a large Colab workbook with lots of functionality) that can be reproduced locally.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.